# how to implement spinner in android without implements?

Tags: android

```
    public class uploadActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
         Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_list);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.spinner_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
     Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected entry in spinner is : " +       parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

i'm trying to add spinner to my class activity but in my project there are 4 button's for which i need OnClickListener to be implemented and i have completed its functionality so i cant change the onclicklistener to OnItemSelectedListener and i m trying bellow method but since i have not implemented OnItemSelectedListener. method like onItemSelected is not called when i click on on entry so how to implement in dis case

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.v("SpinnerSelected Item",
                    "" + spinner.getSelectedItem());
            Log.v("Clicked position",""+position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Log.v("NothingSelected Item",
                    "" + spinner.getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
```

Or, You can use like below

```
public class uploadActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemSelectedListener{
```

Comment: can u tel how to assign values for each entry?

Comment: like in a list thre are say games,home,fashion entries when i click on any one entry from spinner[say games] i want to return some value like for games return value 1 and for homes 2 and for fashion 3 so on

Comment: @andy In `onItemSelected` inside position variable there that will return value 1,2,3, etc.,